File data is lost during the device power-off and power-on test
When the device was testing power off and on, it was found that the content of a json file was missing. The function to operate it is as follows：
    /* 将json写入文件 */
    FILE *pf = fopen(file_path,"w+");
    if( pf == NULL)
    {
        log_e("open %s fail: %s", file_path, strerror(errno));
        goto release_resources;
    }

    log_d("write file %s", cjson_str);
    fwrite(cjson_str,strlen(cjson_str), 1, pf);
    fflush(pf);

The result was beyond my expectation. The left side of the picture below shows a normal file, and the right side shows an error file. They are the same size, but the content of the file on the right side is all 0.
enter image description here
My understanding of the fflush function is that it writes all unwritten data to the file pointed to by pf. If the power is off, the file size will be 0, or only part of it will be written. Is my understanding of the fflush function wrong? I am currently trying to figure out if the power is off during the process of writing a file, will the situation shown in the figure occur? Why is this the case?
Note
My device uses NAND flash, and I will also add fsync() to write it to flash immediately, and add a form of data backup.
thanks!

Just because your program calls fflush() doesn't mean the OS writes the data to disk. Need sync() or fsync() for that.

Thanks for your reply. Actually, what I am more concerned about is that when the operating system writes data to the disk, at which step will it cause the file size to remain unchanged and the content to be all zeros?

If I'm understanding your actual question, what you want to do is write the data into a temporary file in that same location and after the file has been closed rename it to the intended file name. This is the same way browsers download files to "foo...crdownload" before dropping the ".crdownload' extension to make the download "permanent".

I think you misunderstood me. I encountered a situation where the data in a file all became 0 when the device was powered on and off. I want to know what causes the file content to be 0 but the size to remain unchanged. Because in my understanding, power failure during the fwrite process will cause the file to be lost or only part of the data will be written.
